# Exchange Server 2007 is altering href value

Tags: smtp, exchange-server-2007, mailmessage

I am creating an email going out to internal users with the following code that has a link to an internal directory:

```
<a href="\\abc\123">\\abc\123</a>
```

And for whatever reason, the mail that comes in shows:

**`\\abc\123`**   and the link points to **/abc/123**

I am suspecting Exchange Server of somehow altering the mail message to make it less "dangerous", but I am really stuck here since this is a network address, going to internal users!  When they click the link it doesn't show the directory.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally figured this one out.

Exchange takes a lot of liberty when it re-renders the HTML and assumes that you want to put a relative web link versus network path.

That's why all the "\" were converted to "/".

The way around this is to add "file:///" prior to the href address:

```
<a href="file:///\\abc\123">\\abc\123</a>
```

will work!